# Using VS Code to push multiple .py file lines to the python interactive pane

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rstudio, jupyter

I'm having some trouble with pushing multi-line code chunks from a .py script to the interactive python pane in VS code. For reference, I'm moving over from using Rstudio as an IDE and would like the same sort of script-to-console interaction I'm used to from there.

For example, if I tried to run the following lines from a .py script:

```
def f(a):
    print(a)
```

I'm able to run the `def f(a):` line, but rather than wait for the `print(a)` line to be run, the interactive pane tries to run the first line which results in:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block (2416368674.py, line 1)
```

I am able to run multi-line chunks fine if I highlight the entire chunk and push it to the interactive pane.

I generally just want to be able to run multi-line chunks, functions, etc. line by line with the interactive pane knowing to wait if it should expect more code. I don't want to work with wrapping the code in a cell. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The error says your indentation is incorrect,,, That would be the first place I would start. Python is very picky on indentation.

Comment: I think the indentation here isn't the issue, but that the interactive pane is just executing `def f(a):` before I run the next line, where the indentation actually occurs. If I highlight the whole function statement and run it, it runs fine with no indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not do that, it's unreasonable.

No matter you send the codes to the Interactive panel or the REPL in the terminal, it will automatically run the codes -- with an `Enter` press.

You want it without the automatically `Enter` press and wait for you to press it by yourself, or it can be smart enough to know when to keep waiting for the following codes.

But why not sends the code snippet directly instead of line by line and press the `Enter` automatically instead of manually press the `Enter` every time?